# Running MPI benchmarks on multiple nodes?

Tags: mpi

I am trying to run MPI benchmarks on four nodes, but it's always taking only one node. The command I use is as below:

```
mpirun -genv I_MPI_DEBUG=4  -np 4 -host mac-snb19,mac-snb20,mac-snb21,mac-snb22 IMB-MPI1 PingPong
```

or

```
mpirun -genv I_MPI_DEBUG=4  -np 4 --hosts mac-snb19,mac-snb20,mac-snb21,mac-snb22 IMB-MPI1 PingPong
```

Here, `mac-snb19`, `mac-snb20`, `mac-snb21` and `mac-snb22` are the nodes. Am I doing something wrong? Because the output I get shows that only `mac-snb19` is used, and I also check by logging into the node, and only in `mac-snb19` I can see that MPI processes are running, in the others it's not the case. The partial output is here which shows what I said:

```
[0] MPI startup(): 0       2073     mac-snb19  {0,1,2,3,16,17,18,19}
[0] MPI startup(): 1       2074     mac-snb19  {4,5,6,7,20,21,22,23}
[0] MPI startup(): 2       2075     mac-snb19  {8,9,10,11,24,25,26,27}
[0] MPI startup(): 3       2077     mac-snb19  {12,13,14,15,28,29,30,31}
 benchmarks to run PingPong
```

Could you advise me what mistake I am doing here?

Thanks

Comment: Your MPI implementation probably puts the 4 processes consecutively one after the other. If you want to have only one process per node, you need to tell this your MPI for example with -npernode 1. How to exactly achieve this depends on your environment.

Answer (score 1):

With the Hydra process manager, you could either add `-perhost 1` to force one process per host or create a machine file with the following content:

```
mac-snb19:1
mac-snb20:1
mac-snb21:1
mac-snb22:1
```

and then use it like:

```
mpirun -genv I_MPI_DEBUG=4 -machinefile mfname -np 4 IMB-MPI1 PingPong
```

where `mfname` is the name of the machine file. `:1` instructs Hydra to provide only one slot per host.